# Using XAML compiler does not decrease application size

Tags: performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Working on application performance and found this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/xamlc/. It says the final application size will decrease after using,

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

at class level, but my application size increased after using this. It went from 30308kB to 30379kB. I know it's just some kB's but still it increased where as I thought it must decrease. Anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 1):

How many and how large are your `.xaml` files to start with?

Without `XamlCompilation` the `.xaml` is embedded into your assembly and at runtime, extracted and "parsed" into an object tree.

With `XamlCompilation` the `.xaml` is generated into code and thus the `IL` for the resulting code is included within your assembly like any other code would be.

So, the question goes back to if you only have one or two `xaml` files, then the generated code and thus generated `IL` just might be larger, but if you have dozens of templates, styles, pages, etc... then you can save a few bytes. If think about how small the `xaml` text files are to start with, you are not going to save huge amounts of final app size as those `xaml` text embedded resources are now `IL` instructions.

The key features, *for me*, are **#1) the compile-time checking(!)**, and closely behind is #2 the **decrease of instantiation time** of a page, and #3 (last for me) is the saving of a few bytes of app size...

Comment: I have about 10 Xaml Files, I don't think there is a visible difference for my application, but as said will get to know when I have many more Xaml files. Thank You.